# Количество слайдов OwlCarousel 2

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, owl-carousel

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: в слайдере OwlCarousel 2 при разрешении 1920 на 1080 пикселей не отображается необходимое количество слайдов, а именно 4, то есть 3 слайда отображаются полностью, а 4 - только наполовину. Стоит уменьшить размер экрана, появляется полноценный 4 слайд со всей информацией. В опциях к данному слайдеру игрался очень долго, а именно: устанавливал отображение 4 слайдов (items: 4) и устанавливал responsive с разными значениями, но не помогло. Буду рад любой подсказке. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: добавь хотя бы минимальную реализацию с проблемой чтобы можно было поиграться и дать ответ